# function to clean current workspace apart from some variables

Tags: r, scope

How can I write a generic R function that cleans the current workspace apart from some self-defined variables? For sure, I can achieve this in a single script with the following code:

```
prj = '/path/to/project'
src = 'string'
data_to_clean = head(iris)
rm(list = ls()[ !ls() %in% c('prj', 'src') ] )
# only prj and src remain
```

However I want this to be a function, so that it's applicable for multiple scripts and I can change the variables which should not be cleaned, in one place. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wrap this in a function, you have to keep in mind, that a function will create its own environment, when executed. Therefore, you need to specify the environment every time (in each `ls` as well as `rm`). You probably want to remove them from the `.GlobalEnv`.

```
clean_workspace <- function(not_to_be_removed) {
  rm(list = 
    setdiff(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), c("clean_workspace", not_to_be_removed)), 
    envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

prj = '/path/to/project'
src = 'string'
data_to_clean = head(iris)
clean_workspace(c('prj', 'src'))
```

In order not to remove the function itself, it should be added to the values not to be removed.

If you want to read more about environments, have a look a [this overview](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html).

Comment: thanks both of you! It nearly answered my question. To set the variables in "one place" I will just define them within the function. I.e. `function(not_to_be_removed) { not_to_be_removed = c('prj', 'src'); rm(list = 
    setdiff(ls(envir = .GlobalEnv), c("clean_workspace", not_to_be_removed)), 
    envir = .GlobalEnv) }` which I then run at the end of every script

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to remove the function itself. The important bit is to tell `rm` the environment where to remove these objects from:

```r
clean_workspace <- function(not_to_be_removed, envir = globalenv()) {
  objs <- ls(envir = envir)
  rm(list = objs[ !objs %in% not_to_be_removed], envir = envir)
}

prj = '/path/to/project'
src = 'string'
data_to_clean = head(iris)
clean_workspace(c('prj', 'src'))
ls()
#> [1] "prj" "src"
```

Comment: @loki is right. This will clean only the "fresh" environment which is created by the function call. I want a function that cleans the current/global environment.

Comment: Indeed, fixed that I hope.